# Webscraping FBRef

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to webscrape (in R) the 'Player Standard Stats' table from this URL https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/2022-2023/stats/2022-2023-Premier-League-Stats

I have run the following code

```
player <- "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/2022-2023/stats/2022-2023-Premier-League-Stats"
player_log <- player %>% read_html %>%  html_node('#div_stats_standard') %>% html_table()
```

But I am gettting the following error
Error in UseMethod("html_table") :
no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing"

I've tried changing "#div_stats_standard' to '#div_all_stats_standard' but I get the same error. Is someone able to point out where I am going wrong please?

Many thanks

Comment: maybe useful https://npranav10.github.io/blog/scraping_fbref_data.html

Comment: the issue is that every table except for the top 2 are loaded in via javascript (source: tell ublock origin to block javascript, reload the page, and the player stats table doesn't load

Comment: Generally, current browsers offer some kind of document inspector (try `F12` or `CTL`+`SHIFT`+`i` to open) with a selection tool (look for an arrow-pointer icon). Selecting the page element, e. g. the table, will display copious information (HTML, CSS ...) among which you'll find the ID, if any. Right-clicking will also offer some "copy as CSS-selector" option.

Comment: @I_O the issue is the table is javascript - try it out for yourself

Comment: I think there needs to be some kind of check before someone posts an rvest question, that makes them confirm it's not Javascript. I've seen probably a dozen rvest questions in the past month and for every one, the question is always "why can't I scrape x?", and the answer is always "x is Javascript, use RSelenium"

Comment: RSelenium is one option here, but certainly not THE answer.  As with many other sports stats sites, FBRef delivers most tables within HTML comments,  extracting those with `rvest` might not be as trival as `read_html() %>% html_table()`  and one needs to understand the difference between page source and rendered DOM tree, but it's still relatively easy task AND quite well covered with various examples - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45970940/646761 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/59362714/646761,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75056826/646761 (last one targets fbref.com)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to scrape the second table from web page using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75055576/unable-to-scrape-the-second-table-from-web-page-using-r)  All you should need is to change the URL and leave the rest as-is.